# Is there a generic format for core files?

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump

I've noticed that no matter which compiler I use (gcc, llvm, clang, icc, etc.), if I get a core dump, I can almost always just throw it into GDB (or probably other debuggers, but I end up with GDB reflexively most of the time) without worrying about how the program/library was compiled. Why is this? Is there a generic format to describe how core dumps are created? Are there any compiler/debugger combos that don't follow this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core dump files are written by the operating system kernel and not by the compiler or debugger. That's why for e.g. every Linux debugger supports the same format.

Linux core dumps use the ELF format. The kernel side implementation is in [`elf_core_dump()` in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=4.0#L2119).

There are, however, crash-reporting systems like [Crashpad](http://docs.crashpad.googlecode.com/git/doc/index.html) that write out their own core dump equivalents for remote collection. These dumps are much smaller, can include only a list of stack trace addresses and use their own custom format across different operating systems. You'd need to explicitly integrate these as libraries in your apps though.

Answer (score 0):

Core dump format is specific to each operating system default and most common format is ELF.

Userspace core file has many segments/program headers.

Two types of program/segment headers are dumped in a core file

- PT_NOTE
- PT_LOAD

PT_NOTE segment is composed of one or more Elf_Note entries.

PT_LOAD entry in the program header describes VMAs(Virtual Memory Area) of the process

Both Linux and FreeBSD store most data about the process in PT_NOTE segment.

On FreeBSD you can read note segments from core file as below

```
$ readelf --notes hello.core | grep -v "description data:"

Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000200 with length 0x00001d04:
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  FreeBSD              0x00000078       NT_PRPSINFO (prpsinfo structure)
  FreeBSD              0x000000e0       NT_PRSTATUS (prstatus structure)
  FreeBSD              0x00000200       NT_FPREGSET (floating point registers)
  FreeBSD              0x00000018       NT_THRMISC (thrmisc structure)
  FreeBSD              0x00000444       NT_PROCSTAT_PROC (proc data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000aec       NT_PROCSTAT_FILES (files data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000724       NT_PROCSTAT_VMMAP (vmmap data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000038       NT_PROCSTAT_GROUPS (groups data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000006       NT_PROCSTAT_UMASK (umask data)
  FreeBSD              0x000000d4       NT_PROCSTAT_RLIMIT (rlimit data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000008       NT_PROCSTAT_OSREL (osreldate data)
  FreeBSD              0x0000000c       NT_PROCSTAT_PSSTRINGS (ps_strings data)
  FreeBSD              0x00000114       NT_PROCSTAT_AUXV (auxv data)

NT_PRPSINFO - "struct prpsinfo" is dumped
NT_PRSTATUS - "struct prstatus" & "struct __reg64" is dumped
NT_FPREGSET - "struct __fpreg64" is dumped
NT_THRMISC  - "struct thrmisc" is dumped 
NT_PROCSTAT_* - Refer this for proc stat data see libprocstat
```

Below paper has more details on FreeBSD supported core dumps

[The History and Future of Core Dumps in FreeBSD](https://www.bsdcan.org/2017/schedule/attachments/405_freebsd-coredump-history)